# How to create a new random integer between a specif range

Tags: c, gcc, random

I have a range of numbers 1 to 100 which are indices to a list, I need to pick a list at random. If what i am looking for in the list is not found, I need to pick a next random integer within the range which gets me to the list and it should not be the one which was previously selected,,
In there a way to do this efficiently in C. I could do it with shuffling an array of indices but I want to know if there is a better way.

To summarize, i need a very good random algorithm which returns an integer which i know is random and was never used before.

I do know about rand(), srand() and randomize(). I am not sure if these serve the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arc4random_uniform` will do the trick, if available on your system:

```
uint32_t r = 1U + arc4random_uniform(100); // r = 1...100
```

If you need a unique number, begin with an array of values and use a [Fisher-Yates (aka Knuth) shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

If the array is smaller than the range you could just brute force fill with unique random numbers, then shuffle -- i.e. if you needed only ten numbers, then you could generate it in *about* 20 random-gen calls. Note that the shuffle would only be needed in this scenario if you also ordered it during population (for faster match lookups).

Another approach would be to populate a vector [1...100] and draw remaining elements from it at random, removing entries as you used them.

Comment: The Fisher-Yeates solution is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

you can combine your knowledge of  `srand`, `rand` and  `time()` with **% operation**.
% n - gives you **reminder from division** on n, which is obviously can`t be larger when n.
So in terms of code:

```
srand(time());
int value = rand() % n; // will give you random values within interval [0,n)
```

But I need to mention that *rand() has some disadvantages*, one of them that it is not provide uniform distribution, as probability of lower values are higher (you can find discussion related to this topic on stackoverflow)

Comment: See e.g. http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx why this is usually not a good recommendation, I had to -1 this since you imply you know that your solution is bad but propagate it nevertheless.

Comment: I don`t agree with you, I advised to use % operation, which can be combined with any technique of random number generation, which ofcourse is not limited to the rand() function provided in <stdlib>. Also I have pointed out some disadvantage of rand().

Comment: @spin_eight: But you did not mention the real disadvantage of the `%` operator which adds a bias to the results if `n` does not evenly divide `RAND_MAX`.

Comment: @Archie I am not aware of it, can you give me an explanation on bias which arise in that case or some reference on the source where it is explained?

Comment: @spin_eight See this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, very helpfull link and explanation. So % operation works only when RAND_MAX < n and in this case it is usless. +1